# How do i free a Waitblock in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

we are a group of students with not much experience in programming. Our task is to simulate a circular process where doors are undergoing at least 3 processing steps in a milling machine. We want to prioritize the products e.g. if a door with thickness 43mm (red number above the door) is at conveyor 1, then there shouldn't be a door with another thickness on it. Our idea is to use a wait block that should only release the next agent if:
the thickness is the same or conveyer 1 is empty
For that we used the following code in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCT0P.png)

But the code: wait.free(agent.door); doesnt work when the current agent on conveyer 1 leaves it. At proceeding simulation we don`t get an error code. Other ideas are welcome.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

put the same code wait.free(agent) when the current agent on conveyor1 leaves it

on exit you add the code

```
if(wait.size()>0) {
    AgentType x=findFirst(wait,a->a.thickness==conveyorThickness);
    if(x!=null)
           wait.free(x);
}
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, how do we use the code you have provided but with multiple conditions? so for example I need to find the agent based on thickness, width, etc. to free from the wait block. The only method I did is a nested method using findFirst(findAll()), but this only allows an if conditioning. Is there a cleaner method? and also a method that allows or conditioning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: AgentType x=findFirst(wait,a->a.thickness==conveyorThickness && a.width==conveyorWidht && a.other==conveyorOTher && a.etc==conveyorEtc);